# // GET: /Article/{text} in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller named ArticleController with an Index method that returns the Article view.  This works.

However, I'd like to be able to process any text after Article/ in the URL such as Article/someText Article/fileNanme Article/etc

I thought this would be straightforward by implementing the following:

```
// GET: /Article/{text}
public ActionResult Index(string someText)
{
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Update:

See routes:

> ```
>     routes.MapRoute(
>         name: "Articles",
>         url: "Article/{*articleName}",
>         defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Article", id= UrlParameter.Optional }
>         ,
>         constraints: new { therest = @"\w+" }
>     );
>
>  routes.MapRoute(
>         name: "Default",
>         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>         defaults: new {  controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
>     );
> ```

See ArticleController methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
       ...
    }


    public ActionResult Article(string articleName)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: How is your routing config look like? Have you a created a custom routing rule for your action?

Comment: No, the routing config is standard out of the box.

Comment: Yep, it's straight forward, all you need is to use a proper route. See asp.net routing for the details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Just guessing here, you're not thinking that a comment with the route is enough to hook it up, are you?  You need some code for that

Comment: Obviously I am not an idiot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a catch-all parameter to the route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{*therest}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Notice the asterisk? This marks `therest` as a "catch-all" parameter, which will match all remaining segments in the URL.

In your action, you would have

```
public ActionResult Article(string therest)
{
  /*...*/
}
```

This works even for URLs like "Home/Article/This/Is/The/Rest", in which case `therest` will have the value "This/Is/The/Rest".

If you want to leave out the controller part of the URL completely, you would have

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "Article/{*therest}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

which will match URLs like "Article/ThisIs/JustSomeText".

If you want `therest` to at least contain something, you might add a routing constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "Article/{*therest}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                constraints: new { therest = @"\w+" }
            );
```

The constraint is a regular expression that `therest` must match for the route to match.

Stephen Walther has a [nice article on routing and catch-all parameters](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/02/06/chapter-2-understanding-routing).
Stephen Walther, again, has an article on routing constraints [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

Comment: what is the asterisk for?

Comment: The asterisk marks the parameter as a catch-all parameter. It tells the routing engine that this parameter will match all the remaining segments in the URL. Updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: It works if I get rid of my default route, but how do I get both routes to take effect.  Here is my default             routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Try putting the route with the "Article/{*therest}"-url first, before your default route. When a request comes in, the routing engine matches the url with each route in turn in the order you added them. Thus, you should put the least general routes first.

Comment: I get an error "The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'ArticleController' is ambiguous between the following action methods" when I use both routes in any order.  If I comment one out and use the other and vice versa then I am able to use Index() and Index(string) actions.  I can't seem to get it to work so that Article/ and Article/asdasd go to different controller actions.

Comment: I don't want to change the default route too much, as it's useful for other parts of my app.

Comment: The error you mention above is not caused by routing per se, but by the fact that you have two methods called Index in the same controller. ASP.NET MVC does not use the method signature to determine which action to invoke. Instead, if you have multiple actions with the same name, you need to disambiguate them using an attribute like [HttpPost] (which means this action will only serve POST requests) or something similar.

Comment: Ok, so I change my new route default action to "Article" and rename the Index(string) action in the controller to Article(string)..  but it doesn't work.  I get the first(default) route working (/Article), but the new route doesn't work when I go /Article/thisIsAnArticle

Comment: Sorry, I've lost track of what is the current status of your routes and actions. Did you add the constraint I mention in the answer?

Comment: I added the constraint yes.  So what is happening now is I can navigate to Article/ and that will trigger my Index action.  I can navigate to Article/sdfasdffads and that gives a 404.  I can navigate to Article/Article/sdfasdfasdf and that triggers my Article action - but it's not what I want. 
I can't seem to get both routes to work simultaneously....

Comment: Your catch-all parameter is called "articleName" but you put the constraint on a (non-existing) parameter called "therest"

Comment: Good catch.  It works now, but I don't understand why.  How could the constraint on the custom route make it work when it wouldn't work before.  I read the link you gave me, but can't see a correlation.  Any idea?

Comment: To me the constraint is used to force numeric or text only input.  But I don't care if I accept both.  I just want the action to fire in the cae of "Action/somethingOrSomeNumber" and "Action" as two separate action methods.  So, I don't get why the constraint...

Comment: Change the constraint to ".+", then the first route will only match if articleName satisfies the constraint, ie, is non-empty. Thus, the URL "Article" will not match and the next (default) route will be used.

Comment: Ok, I sort of understand.  I'm still wrapping my head around why it matters, but I'll get there eventually once I better grasp the routing model.  Thanks for your help.  Great help here! +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standard routing change parameter name from `someText` to `id`. Otherwise you have to create custom routing for this parameter

Comment: There isn`t type text. `string` is exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route in order to use the url you mentioned. For the latest MVC4, routes file exists in this directory App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

add this new route about the the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Custom",
            url: "Article/{someText}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Try loading your url now. It should work now.